# Changing permissions

Tags: linux, unix, chmod

Beginner in Linux/Unix here having an issue with changing the permissions of a file.
I put in the command line:
chmod u+rwx, g+r, o+r file1
But got an error message saying "chmod: invalid mode: `u+rwx,' try`chmod --help' for more information.
I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
There was no permissions on the file to begin with either.

Comment: It looks like you inadvertently included an extra `+` in your command when you typed it. First rule of debugging: read the error message carefully.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using spaces after the commas in your `chmod` command? If so, remove them.

`chmod u+rwx,g+r,o+r file1` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numerical values, where 4=r, 2=w, 1=x (there are others but this answers the OP), you add up the permissions you want and then provide 3 values to chmod for User Group and Other:

```
chmod 744 file1   (u=rwx,g=r,o=r)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check if you are giving space after ","**

```
chmod u=rwx, g=rx, o=r file_name   => It will give invalid mode

chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=r file_name     => It will get executed
```